# geom_mark_ellipse error when using 2 points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

The ellipse marked by `geom_mark_ellipse` in `ggforce` package does not work correctly when using two points.

Following I show the example

Data:

```
          transecta        MDS1         MDS2              grupo
CLOA1         CLOA1  0.56852742  0.294150091       mmx clausura
CLOA2         CLOA2  0.88257101  0.151361099       mmx clausura
CLOA3         CLOA3  1.05422157  0.202652263  pastizal clausura
CLOA6         CLOA6  0.34475209 -0.168575457       mmx clausura
CLOA7         CLOA7 -0.73184407 -0.277142902        ba clausura
CLOA8         CLOA8 -0.03496517 -0.732031748        ba clausura
OAT1           OAT1 -0.51507135  0.424460141      mmx transecta
OAT2           OAT2 -0.15854319  0.266485510      mmx transecta
OAT3           OAT3 -0.86233409  0.022687344      mmx transecta
OATCOI1     OATCOI1 -0.86519268 -0.004470466       ba transecta
OATCOI3     OATCOI3 -0.86632557  0.230568674       ba transecta
OATCOIEC1 OATCOIEC1 -0.80751803  0.320056234       ba transecta
OATMMX3     OATMMX3 -0.42566740 -0.110641894      mmx transecta
OATMMXEC2 OATMMXEC2 -0.09455770  0.760007755      mmx transecta
OATP1         OATP1  0.36207279  0.424046062 pastizal transecta
OATP2         OATP2  0.56614390  0.470124863 pastizal transecta
```

Code:

```
library(ggplot2);library(ggforce)
gg1<-ggplot(data,aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2)) + 
  # stat_contour(data=ordi.AC.na, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z),  binwidth = 5,alpha=0.9) +
  # geom_raster(data=ordi.AC.na, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = z,alpha=0.9)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=grupo)) + 
  geom_mark_ellipse(aes(color=grupo)) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=transecta,color=grupo)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank());gg1
```

Result:

[GGPLOT RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZxtC.png)

Comment: Appears to be unresolved [ggforce issues](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/issues/214), though seems similar enough to your case.

Comment: Two points define a straight line, not a curve, closed or not. I say this without having looked at the code so feel free to disregard my comment.

Comment: Ellipses have two center points.